# Is there a way to simply reset the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

This is my code as of now; at the bottom I have a button to reset my game call tryAgain.  This does just that, but with some issues. Issue 1; after the game is reset using the code I have, sometimes I am unable to click on random buttons.  Issue 2; I have a hove featured styled with css, that disappears upon reset.  I do understand that I change the background color to white, but that's because the buttons would just remain grey and I don't want that, is there a solution for that?  Issue 3; After a second time of restarting the game, my number of tires decreased from 10 to 9 which it should only decrease with the click of an incorrect letter button.  Too many issues, i've tried debugging, i'd rather just reset the DOM, and avoid all the issues.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

```js
// Array of words
const words = [ "planet", "stars", "astroid", "moon", "satilite", "orbit", "universe", "umbra", "lunar", "space", "astronomy", "eclipse", "nebula", "mars", "meteorite"];

// guesses Array
let myGuesses = [];

//variables"
let wordSpace = " - ";
let guess = " ";
let space; //number of spaces in word

//score
let tries = 10;
let counter;
//Get random word
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);

//play function
function play() {
  let userInput = prompt(`would you like to play spaceman? (Y/N)`, "Y");
  console.log(words[index]);

  for (let i = 0; i < words[index].length; i++) {
    console.log(words[0][i]);

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("letters");
    div.innerHTML = " - "; //words[0][i]
    document.querySelector(".word-space").append(div);
  }
}
//handle click function, inactivates buttons once clicked
let handleclick = (e) => {
  e.target.removeEventListener("click", handleclick);
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  myGuesses.push(e.target.innerHTML);
  console.log(myGuesses);
  console.log(words[index].includes(e.target.innerHTML));
  if (words[index].includes(e.target.innerHTML)) {
    document.querySelector(".word-space").innerHTML = "  ";

    for (let i = 0; i < words[index].length; i++) {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.classList.add("letters");
      if (myGuesses.includes(words[index][i])) {
        div.innerHTML = words[index][i];
      } else {
        div.innerHTML = " - ";
      }

      document.querySelector(".word-space").append(div);
    }
    getNumOfTries();
  } else {
    tries--;
    getNumOfTries();
  }
};

function ans() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  buttons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", handleclick));
}
ans();

function getNumOfTries() {
  console.log(tries);
  const showTries = document.querySelector("#myTries");
  showTries.innerHTML = " You have " + tries + " tries";
  if (tries < 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      prompt(`Would you like to try again? (Y,N)`, "Y");
      showTries.innerHTML = "You loose!";
    }, 2000);
  }
  // if(tries > 0  && words[index].length === myGuesses.length) {
  Array.from(!document.querySelectorAll(".letters")).forEach((letter) => {
    console.log(letter.innerHTML);
  });
  if (
    tries > 0 &&
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".letters")).every(
      (letter) => letter.innerHTML !== " - "
    )
  ) {
    // showTries.innerHTML = 'You Win!'
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(`You Win!`);
      showTries.innerHTML = "You Win!";
    }, 1000);
  }
}

//game reset

let tryAgain = document.querySelector(".Try-Again");
tryAgain.addEventListener("click", () => {
  myGuesses = [];
  tries = 10;
  wordSpace = " - ";
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  document.querySelector(".word-space").innerHTML = "";
  let showTries = document.querySelector("#myTries");
  showTries.innerHTML = "Try Again";
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  buttons.forEach((button) => (button.style.backgroundColor = "white"));

  ans();
  play();
});

play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the original dom state into a variable during page load

```
let defaultDomState = document.body.innerHTML;
```

When you need to reset, just replace the current body

```
document.body.innerHTML = defaultDomState;
```

Comment: how to I save the original Dom state? where do I find that info? I'm sorry I'm new to this just started leaving 8 weeks ago lol.

Comment: @Tamara You can add the first line to your code's first line (before `const words = [...`) and the 2nd line can be put as the first line of the `tryAgain` click function.